# Sherlock actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent) leaves gap to left

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have tried searching on Google and stackoverflow but I didn't find the solution.

**Problem:**

[image: gap_img]

**Code:**

```
actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
//actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
//actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
//actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);

LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(v, lp);

actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

**header.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/topheaderbackground" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topcaption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textColor="#ebf5ff"
        android:textSize="9.6pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**What I have tried:**

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

**But result is:**

[image]

Please Help!!!

**[Edit]:**

I am using `Theme.Sherlock`.

**[Result of Doctoror Drive's suggestion]:**

`actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.topheaderbackground));`

new **header.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topcaption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textColor="#ebf5ff"
        android:textSize="9.6pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

As you can see text is not in center, any suggestion???

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @blackbelt, I want blue header with text at top with no gaps and tabs below the header.

Comment: Post your layout code where you hearder resides.

Comment: @GrIsHu, I am adding the header layout as custom view in actionBar. As you can see in code.

Comment: Is your `@drawable/topheaderbackground` image or xml file ? If xml please show the code of that file.

Comment: @GrlsHu, it's an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the icon, it's a CustomView that's leaving the gap.
You should change the color of ActionBar in styles.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#AdvancedStyles

And then add custom view with no background, just a TextView in center.

EDIT:
After you've set it to center, the space for your text is space of actionbar content minus the size of icon to the left (which is transparent). Try setting ActionBar display options.
remove

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

and add instead

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Tell me if you still have the issue, then I will tell plan B.

**EDIT, plan B:**

Alright, there is a problem with flipping when above is set so try adding padding to root of your TextView. Set ActionBar mode:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM |
        ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

And in xml, I think the LinearLayout there is useless. Try setting plain and clean TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topcaption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ABC"
    android:textColor="#ebf5ff"
    android:textSize="9.6pt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />
```

If that will not work, try

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topcaption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textColor="#ebf5ff"
        android:textSize="9.6pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hey, I tried what you said, it's working, but text is not aligned in center. Any suggestions???

Comment: Thanks for help, but result is inverted, i.e. header is below tabs. [the image I posted below the title `But result is:`]. please tell me plan B.

Comment: Updated again, fixed one thingie and added proposal of removing TextView's parent.

Comment: error: `?android:attr/actionBarSize requires API level 11 (current min is 10)`

Comment: I found it in sherlock library `?attr/actionBarSize`.

Comment: Hurrahh.....it's working, big salute to Doctoror Drive for spending his precious time.